Adding liquidity for honeypot scam tokens
I have bought into my share of honeypot scam tokens over the years. I am not sore about it - I accept it as an 'operating cost' of trading in risky tokens. But I was curious whether I could take these tokens which I can't sell and pair them with a bit of WETH to add back liquidity while the token is still climbing in a straight-line trajectory - i.e. before the rugpull? I tried to put it test with a very small amount after picking out a random honeypot token on Dexscreener (which wasn't very hard lol). On Uniswap V2, after entering in my liquidity settings, I got to the final 'Preview' step. But after that it just kept failing to prepare the transaction. Is this because the token owner is somehow able to prevent 3rd parties from supplying liquidity?

So you are trying to scam more people. Scammer are quite clever I doubt that a new programmer will do better than them.

No I am finding a way to recover my funds if I end up buying scam tokens in the future again. Yes, maybe I should avoid risky tokens but I have generally found the trade to be net profitable.
